# React Navigation 4 Deep Linking is not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I am using react-navigation-4. I was in `expo` and ejected from that using bare workflow.
Now I want to use deep linking so that when I want to click on a notification, it goes to a certain screen in my app.

I followed the instructions in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/deep-linking but when I using `Linking.openURL("rnfarmer://submitrating/dd");` to open screen, nothing happens.

This is my App.js :

```
import React from "react";

import MyNavigator from "./navigation/MyNavigator";

export default function App() {

  const prefix = 'rnfarmer://';

  return <MyNavigator uriPrefix={prefix}  />;
}
```

This is MyNavigator.js file :

```
...
export default createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({SubmitRating: {
screen: SubmitRatingScreen,
path: 'submitrating/:orderId'


}}));
```

and also I've added these lines to AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="rnfarmer" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

I am using DrawerNavigator so I have a nested navigation and because of that I should add path to parent navigator and then to the child.

EDIT

Example :
This is your Main Navigator:

```
const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  MainNav: {
    screen: FarmerNavigator,
    path: "main"
  } ,
  ProfileNav: FillProfileNavigator,
  MyOrdersNav: MyOrdersNavigator,
  RatingNav: RatingNavigator,
  RulesNav: RulesNavigator,
  AboutAppNav: AbouAppNavigator
}, {
  drawerPosition: "right",
  contentComponent: DrawerContent,
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: FarmerColors.colorPrimary,
    itemsContainerStyle: {
      marginVertical: 0,
    },
    iconContainerStyle: {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
});
```

And this is your Farmer Navigator:

```
const AsanZeraatNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  ShowLand: ShowLandScreen,
  ShowOrder: {
    screen: ShowOrderScreen,
    path: 'showorder/:params'
  },
  SubmitRating: {
    screen: SubmitRatingScreen,
    path: 'submitrating/:params',
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you share a snippet as an example?

Comment: pls share a snippet of your code on this pls